# DD4t 2011 site, doesn't hit page controller & keeps getting 404

Tags: 2011, dd4t

I have a DD4T 2011 site.  I get a 404 for every URL & no requests are going to the page controller.  Any ideas on what the issue could be?  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is in web.config.  Could this be a license issue?  I found the entry below in the log, so it looks like the license is ok.  I don't see any errors in my log

```
2014-08-05 14:15:20,460 DEBUG LicenseReader - Found license entry for Tridion CD Broker, trying to validate this license key
2014-08-05 14:15:20,460 DEBUG LicenseReader - There was no licenseLock Location specified, using user.home var: C:\
2014-08-05 14:15:20,460 DEBUG LicenseReader - There was no licenseLock Location specified, using user.home var: C:\
2014-08-05 14:15:20,460 DEBUG LicenseReader - Found options Tridion CD Broker=true
2014-08-05 14:15:20,460 DEBUG LicenseReader - Found Key Tridion CD Broker, Value true
```

**Update**

These are my route entries.  I commented out the site edit config for now.  This looks like a straight MVC issue, not a DD4T one.

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    /////Route for SDL Tridion UI 2011 (Aka !SiteEdit)
    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    "SiteEditBlankPage",
    //    "se_blank.html",
    //    new { controller = "Empty", action = "Index" });

    //Tridion page route
    routes.MapRoute(
       "TridionPage",
       "{*PageId}",
       new { controller = "Page", action = "Page" }, // Parameter defaults
       new { pageId = @"^(.*)?$" } // Parameter constraints
   );


    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Comment: can't really help here, but wanted to share that indeed it doesn't look like a licensing issue. Are you sure the DD4T modules/handlers/whatever-they-are are being called?

Comment: Can you share your route configuration, usually in Global.asax

Comment: finally found the issue.  I'd linked the project to MVC 4.  The version of DD4T for tridion 2011 must use MVC 3.  Whazt threw me was that there was no error that I could find, I just got a "page not found" error.  Doesn't DD4T have its own logs?  I should have looked there.

Comment: DD4T has its own logs, it can use Logback or MS Enterprise logging. You do have to configure it though. From the top of my head an appSettings key telling which log implementation to use and a normal logger configuration element (depending on logback / MS logging) should be in web.config

Comment: Which version of DD4T are you using? We're successfully using Tridion 2011 SP1 with DD4T 1.31 against MVC5 without recompiling the framework. Prior to 1.30 the MVC version mattered more.

Comment: +1 to the question, comments, and confirming the issue. Definitely consider moving the follow-up comment into an answer.

Comment: When you upgrade your application to use 2013 GA or 2013 SP1 Tridion content delivery jar/dll you must use DD4T 1.31 as component presentation are now encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue. I'd linked the project to MVC 4. The version of DD4T for tridion 2011 must use MVC 3. What threw me was that there was no specific error that I could find, I just got a "page not found" error.

Per Rob Stevenson-Leggett, make sure you are using DD4T 1.30 or later if you want to use MVC 4 or 5.

Comment: As I said on my comment, I'm not convinced this was your issue. We've used DD4T with MVC4 and Tridion 2011 SP1. Which DD4T version are you using exactly?

Comment: that's it then. I was using 1.25. I didn't see your comment.  It was hidden under "show one more comment"